# Error - Custom Reports

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When I try to get custom report in MS Dynamics CRM 2013, after 5-6 minutes later I get this error:[image]

If the report is not huge, then there is no error. But if it is huge, it give me this error.

And this is the trace : 
  at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Ex
webserver!ReportServer_0-13!b298!03/06/2015-12:34:46:: e ERROR: Reporting Services error Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DSMain. ---> Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtensionShim.Common.ReportExecutionException: 
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: An unexpected error occurred.
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: The fetch data set query timed out after 404.9472744 seconds. Increase the query timeout, and try again. ---> Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtensionShim.Common.ReportExecutionException: An unexpected error occurred. ---> Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtensionShim.Common.ReportExecutionException: The fetch data set query timed out after 404.9472744 seconds. Increase the query timeout, and try again.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Did you try this?:   " Increase the query timeout, and try again"?

Comment: I know this is an option. But how much increase ? Is this most effective solution ?

Comment: Either increase the timeout as much as it takes, or make your query faster so that it doesn't time out.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at the query to see if there is a way to optimize it before extending the timeout.

Additionally, I would see if there are ways to optimize the report by adding indexes (indicies?) using something like the Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

Obviously, there will be an inherent limitation on how big the report is. If the report has enough data and is long enough, increasing the timeout might be the only practical option.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I wonder if there is any other solution, like merging or adding reports. Do you know something like that ?

Comment: @tottotech, I'm afraid I don't know what you mean when you say merging or adding reports. Can you explain?

Comment: Ok. The my problem is the report is too big. What I am asking is, can I seperate the report. In my case, report depents on dates. So, Can I ask reports by separating dates and then combine them. So client sees one report.

Comment: I would agree with this. If a query is taking 5/6 minutes to run then either the query is fundamentally wrong (maybe using loops/cursors instead of joins), some indexes may be missing, or maybe the report requirements need to be revisited. If the query is fine and all indexes in place, I'd favour pushing back on the requirements as opposed to increasing the timeout. Having long running queries on your database might just introduce other problems you don't want happening.